# how to stream eclipse view console to a file on startup from plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, stream, jconsole

I wrote a plugin to eclipse and I tried to stream the eclipse console content with Istratup to a file by using (System.out) on TeePrintStream but the problem is the console is being streamed to the file is the plugins console and not the main program's console.

does anyone know how to stream the main program's console?

the earlyStartup() method:

```
public void earlyStartup() 
{
    try 
    {
        FileOutputStream file = new FileOutputStream("c:/test/test.txt");
        TeePrintStream tee = new TeePrintStream(file, System.out);
        System.setOut(tee);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the teePrintStream is customized.. ask me to upload if needed.

Comment: What do you mean by "main program's console"?

Comment: I developed this plugin and installed it so it will stream out the projects console(exception i\o etc...) I'm currently working on(j2ee) to a file on startup but instead the plugin streamed out its console.

Comment: its kind of hard to explain I hope it was clear enough

Comment: When you run a program from within Eclipse a new JVM is started so you can't just look at System.out. Eclipse provides a number of Console interfaces and extension points from dealing with console output